# Interpreting an image taken over a one-year period

Tags: large-datasets

I found this dataset: [Global Aboveground and Belowground Biomass Carbon Density Maps](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_ORNL_biomass_carbon_density_v1)  that's supposed to contain data for all 2010, but it actually just contains one image (size is =1).

Should I assume this image represents the average over that year?

Comment: Raster data like this is usually a snapshot in time (but derived from multiple images in a time window), but you should review the metadata for a description of the methodology.

Comment: This is when it gets tricky to me. If this is a snapshot in time, how could it be derived from a time window? There has to some operation to achieve this, right?

Comment: All imagery have some duration for capture, often referred to as exposure time. In this case, consider that the exposure time (or 'time window') is much longer duration than a typical shutter image, so on the order of months rather than seconds.

Comment: Spaceborne imagery doesn't generally capture even *half* the globe at once, much less both hemispheres, and certainly not at a resolution to make capture worth the effort for this application.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, you can assume that the data were collected over the entire year of 2010.

This particular dataset was generated by combining two different aboveground biomass maps. The primary source was created using a combination of spaceborn optical and SAR imagery over the course of the year 2010 and the other was a separate project used to account for the presence of smaller trees and shrubs such as those in African savannahs.

From the supporting literature:

[image]

AND

[image]

Source: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41597-020-0444-4

Comment: Thanks! I want to kind of associate this data to actual, normal images, so I guess I could get away with it by using the mean of images over the year.